# PyQt5 GUI is working, but still getting errors?

Tags: python, linux, driver, pyqt5, archlinux

i was given a virtual disk image, containing a Arch Linux x86_64 setup, running on a plasma desktop. I am running it on the most up to date version of Oracle VM VirtualBox

I have some simple python file called testWindow.py, utilizing the PyQt5 package, that i installed with pacman

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

import sys

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.title = "Title"
          self.left = 10
          self.top = 10
          self.width = 640
          self.height = 480
          self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
          self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)
          self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
       app = QApplication(sys.argv)
       ex = App()
       sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i run this with:

```
$ python testWindow.py
```

This works good and a window pops up as expected, although in the terminal there are 3 lines that popup that i am not sure what they mean, and they don't stop the program..

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 6: 80ee:beef, driver(null)
libGL error: No driver found
libGL error: failed to load driver: (null)
```

I have tried for a while to look up a solution from posts with similar problems, but all of their problems stem from trying to load a package that is not "null", so my problem is i don't even know what i should be trying to install to get rid of this error because everything is working anyway(that i can see).

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It seems that VirtualBox does not handle the drivers correctly, I use arch linux as the main system and I do not have those problems.

Comment: See [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12746?cversion=1&cnum_hist=21) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/8x4wrp/virtualbox_has_anyone_gotten_archlinux_guest_with/).